# password protect SPSS syntax for open, but not executing

Tags: passwords, spss

Is it possible to password-protect an SPSS syntax, so that users are able to run the syntax, but not able to open or see the code inside it ?

The `INSERT FILE`command can be used to call the file, but I don't want the users to open it and see the contents of the file.

Thanks!

Comment: in SPSS v.22+ you can encrypt syntax files (save as: encrypted), but then `insert`ing the file results in a catastrophic error...  If you find a solution for this one please share here...

Comment: Yes, I saw the error. According to the official documentation, you can encrypt, and need password to decrypt. Period. Nothing about encryption with option to run...  seems very odd to not have an option to protect your shared work...